# Почему маркер не устанавливается?

Tags: javascript, карты, openstreetmap, openlayers

Задача в том, чтобы маркер ставился в заданную из переменной точку. Если заменить в параметре geometry переменную geoposition на конкретные координаты - маркер установится, если же ставить переменную - маркера не будет, без каких-либо ошибок в консоли. В чём заключается проблема?

```js
geoposition = '38.997190, 45.130683';// координаты нужной позиции, на которую будет установлен маркер

//Создание иконки местонахождения пользователя
    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([geoposition], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        name: 'Null Island',
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
            anchor: [0.511, 310],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 1,
            scale: .2,
            src: 'images/phGeoPos.png'
        }))
    });

    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [iconFeature]
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });
//Создание карты на сайте
function loadMap() {
    var centerpos = [38.997190, 45.130683];
    var newpos = ol.proj.transform(centerpos, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    const map = new ol.Map({
        // устанавливает вид на заданное место и масштаб
        view: new ol.View({
            center: newpos,
            projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            zoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 5,
            extent: [4262967.307515293, 5592508.683331995, 4429711.492867963, 5697114.645076073]
        }),
        minExtent: 10,
        // добавляет тайловый слой OpenStreetMap
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    tileSize: 512,
                    maxResolution: 180 / 512,
                    wrapX: true,
                })
            }),
            vectorLayer,
        ],
        keyboardEventTarget: document,
        target: 'map',
    });

    map.on('click', function (e) {
        let coord = e.coordinate
        console.log(coord);
    })
}

//Получение координат пользователя сайта (работает только если на устройстве есть датчик)
function coordinateUser() {
    var writeCoord = document.getElementById('coord');
    var msg = 'Координаты отсутствуют.';
    console.log(navigator.geolocation);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        writeCoord.textContent = 'Определение местоположения..';
    } else {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var lat = (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(8);
        var lon = (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(8);
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        msg = `${lat}, ${lon} <br>погрешность(в метрах): ${accuracy}`;
        writeCoord.innerHTML = msg;
        //geoposition = `${lon},${lat}`
    }
    function error(msg) {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
        console.log(msg.code);
    }
}
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const randomNumber = Math.random();
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (randomNumber < .6) {
            resolve('Все прошло отлично!');
        } else {
            reject('Что-то пошло не так');
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил данную проблему путём поиска координат с помощью встроенных средств openlayers, вместо навигатора.

```js
    // Создание слоя OSM на странице сайта
var centerpos = [38.997190, 45.130683];
var newpos = ol.proj.transform(centerpos, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    // Установка визуализации OSM
var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:900913',
    center: newpos,
    zoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 5,
    extent: [4262967.307515293, 5592508.683331995, 4429711.492867963, 5697114.645076073]
});
    // Установка слоя ОСМ
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                tileSize: 512,
                maxResolution: 180 / 512,
                wrapX: true,
                view: view,
            }),
        })],
    keyboardEventTarget: document,
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
    minExtent: 10,
});
    // Получить координаты щелчком мыши
map.on('click', function (e) {
    let coord = e.coordinate
    console.log(coord);
})
    //Создание иконки местонахождения пользователя
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
    trackingOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
    },
    projection: view.getProjection(),
});

function el(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

el('whereAmI').addEventListener('change', function () {
    geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);
    console.log(geolocation.projection);
});

var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();

geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function () {
    accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
    console.log(accuracyFeature);
});

var positionFeature = new ol.Feature();

positionFeature.setStyle(
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#3399CC',
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#fff',
                width: 2,
            }),

        }),
    })
);

geolocation.on('change:position', function () {
    var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
    positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
});

new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature],
    }),
});
```